# How to move the Tastypie meta information out to the http headers

Tags: python, http, rest, tastypie

Does anyone know what's the 'best' way to move the meta information that gets returned with every request out to the http headers instead??

I was planning to do something like this:

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self,request,data_dict):
        if isinstance(data_dict,dict):
            if 'meta' in data_dict:
                # grab each property of the data_dict['meta'] 
                #and put it on the request headers
            if 'objects' in data_dict:
                return data_dict['objects']
```

Any suggestions from someone that has already done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean move the meta information from the serialized data tastypie returns to the HTTP headers of the *response*, I think you'll need to override the `create_reponse` method instead.  You don't have an HttpResponse object available from `alter_list_data_to_serialize`.  Something like this should get you started:

```
def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs):
    stripped_data = data.get('objects') or data
    desired_format = self.determine_format(request)
    serialized = self.serialize(request, stripped_data, desired_format)
    response = response_class(content=serialized,
                              content_type=build_content_type(desired_format),
                              **response_kwargs)
    # Convert meta data to HTTP Headers 
    for name, value in data.get('meta', {}).items():
        response[name] = str(value)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody needs the same thing, this is how I was able to get it working... Thanks to GregM.

I created a class that inherits from tastypie ModelResource and made the adjustments to it. Then, all my resources use my class instead.

From his code, I just had to add a couple of try, except because when you GET a single item E.g. .../api/v1/user/2/ the meta doesn't exist and there is an AttributeError exception being thrown.

Then, you should be good to go.

```
class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    def create_response(self, request, data, response_class=HttpResponse, **response_kwargs):
        try:
            stripped_data = data.get('objects')
        except AttributeError:
            stripped_data = data
        desired_format = self.determine_format(request)
        serialized = self.serialize(request, stripped_data, desired_format)
        response = response_class(content=serialized,
                                  content_type=build_content_type(desired_format),
                                  **response_kwargs)
        # Convert meta data to HTTP Headers
        try:
            for name, value in data.get('meta', {}).items():
                response['Meta-' + name.title().replace('_','-')] = str(value)
        except AttributeError:
            response['Meta-Empty'] = True
        return response
```

Again, full credit to Greg, thanks.